# Two line graph in R

Tags: r, graph, line, linechart, linegraph

I have this data frame 'xy':

```
 mean_name mean_T_S mean_SIH
1      Action        3 3.272727
2  Reflection        5 4.727273
3 Flexibility        4 5.136364
4   Structure        3 2.636364
```

and want to have a line chart plotting two lines (one for mean_T_S and one for mean_SIH).

I tried changing the data frame 'xy' to this format

```
    mean_name      key    value
1      Action mean_SIH 3.272727
2  Reflection mean_SIH 4.727273
3 Flexibility mean_SIH 5.136364
4   Structure mean_SIH 2.636364
5      Action mean_T_S 3.000000
6  Reflection mean_T_S 5.000000
7 Flexibility mean_T_S 4.000000
8   Structure mean_T_S 3.000000
```

and then tried

```
xyplot <- ggplot(xy, aes(x=mean_name, y=xy$value, colour=xy$key)) + geom_line()
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Appreciating any help!

Comment: You don't need the `xy$`, you can just use the bare variable name. I'm not sure that should cause an actual error though. Maybe double check the new format of xy is actually saved into xy?

Comment: `matplot(xy[2:3])` is a base R way to do it, for your first version of the data frame.

Comment: @Elle thanks for the tips, sadly it still doesn't work ...

Comment: @dash2 I'm not sure how I can use this to solve my problem

Comment: It plots the 2nd and 3rd columns of the xy data frame. `?matplot` will give more details, including how to draw lines.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you're trying to plot a discreet `x` variable on a line (which needs a continuous variable), you may start like this

```r
df <- read.table(text = ' mean_name mean_T_S mean_SIH
1      Action        3 3.272727
2  Reflection        5 4.727273
3 Flexibility        4 5.136364
4   Structure        3 2.636364', header = T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(!mean_name) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = mean_name, y = value, color = name), position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>